# How to develop java only parts in android

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an Android App. It consists of three parts:

- client (the app)
- server (java-only)
- domain (used by client AND server)

How can I develop client and server in one Eclipse project? There must be a way to set the correct java-only environment (jre7) for a package instead of the AndroidVM.

If I try to launch a class, the console log is the following:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference
```

...even if I've changed the JRE in the running configuration.

Comment: I thought about it. But I think it to be overkill for my small project.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want one Eclipse project for this? I suspect that this would be simpler with 2 or even 3 separate projects.

Comment: I thought about that too. But how do I keep the included libraries up to date without Maven?

Comment: @JosuaSchmid But I'm warning you: Eclipse + Maven + Android might be a nightmare.

Comment: That's why I don't want to use Maven ;-)

Comment: It's not overkill to do this in 3 projects. You have three distinct problems which have unique properties related to their construction. It's not as complicated as you probably think. Don't fight against the methodology, use it to your advantage ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want one set of classes to be running against the AndroidVM and one against jre7.
The whole idea of having projects in eclipse is that they maintain their own separate environment for convenience.  Eclipse handles all of the crazy stuff for you and you get to write code against whatever environment you want.

Additionally, if you are trying to put this under version control, you will have to find a way of splitting the project in half, likely preventing you from using any eclipse plugins from handling it.  If you don't, you end up having to push a "new" version of both the client and the server even if you only want to update one.

Sorry if I'm way off in the weeds, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The version issue opened my mind. It would be a design flaw if I'd merge these three mini-projects. I'll create three seperate projects. But I'm not accepting it as answer, since it is not the answer to the problem. But thank you very much.

Comment: Sure thing.  I agree that its not really a direct answer to the question.  I don't have comment privileges yet but I wanted to help out...  You could obviously hack something together, it just wouldn't be pretty.  I'm interested to see if anyone might have a simple way of binding the client and server, possibly through branches or something.